# Access internal files after built - Cordova

Tags: android, file, cordova

I am wondering if is possible accessing the internal files of an app after build with cordova plugin.

My project is based on Android and here are my files:

`index.html
html:
 - remove.html
js
css`

So, after build the app, I want to access with some option within the app the remove.html and remove it.
I find that the FILE plugin of cordova is useful for files inside the device but not the app.
Please anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

we do not have modification access to the location where apk's internal files are saved. Since your remove.html is part of your app apk, we cannot just remove it.

You can take the same approach taken by sqlite raw database file. When your app is started or run for the very first time, copy your file (`remove.html`) to data folder where you can modify/delete it. Make sure your app only uses this new path everywhere.

Take a look at `copyDatabaseFromAssets` [function in this code](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetHelper.java) for a sample on how do this. Since you will have modification access, you can delete or modify this file as needed.